# What is going on inside quantum gates physically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-computer

What are the physical realities of the different quantum gates? I am particularly interested in how the CNOT gate works on the inside as well as how the Hadamard gate works. The Hadamard gate to me is strange because my assumption on superposition was that a particle left undisturbed would naturally assume a superposition, but that cannot be how a Hadamard gate functions because the same process that puts the qubit into superposition also has to be reversible to take that particle out of superposition and into the original state.

Any intuition or articles on the physics going on inside quantum gates would be appreciated.

Comment: "physical realities"???

Comment: asking how a quantum gate is physically implemented is akin to asking how a logical gate is physically implemented. These are abstractions of the operation of physical devices. How they are implemented is totally dependent on which physical implementation one is considering.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I interpreted it as physical *realisation*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how it is implemented in a Josephson junction, but if we were working with photons, one way to realise the action of the Hadamard gate is by using a perfect beam splitter.

### Operator

In particular, the Hadamard gate is given by:
$$H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$$

In comparison, the action of a beam splitter with reflectivity $r$ and transmittivity $t$ is given by

$$H=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
r & t \\
t & -r
\end{array}\right]$$
with $r=t=1/\sqrt 2$ for a perfect beam splitter.

---

### Physical intuition

Consider the following setup. There are two input modes. Namely $1$, corresponding to the state $|10\rangle_1$ and $2$, corresponding to the state $|01\rangle_2$. Similarly the output modes are $3$, corresponding to the state $|10\rangle_3$ and $4$, corresponding to the state $|01\rangle_4$.

[image]

If a photon is incoming in mode 1, then after passing through the beam splitter it is in a superposition of two output modes whose weights are given by the Hadamard gate. Similarly for a photon in mode 2.

$$|01\rangle_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\big(|10\rangle_3 + |01\rangle_4 \big)$$
$$|10\rangle_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\big(-|10\rangle_3 + |01\rangle_4 \big)$$

Now consider the input state in an equal superposition of the two modes. What will be the corresponding output mode?

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \big(|01\rangle_1+|10\rangle_2\big) = |01\rangle_4$$
As you can see, the output is now a single mode! How is that possible? Well, the amplitudes going to mode 3 from mode 1 and 2, destructively interfered. The reason they did so is because of the emergence of a phase difference of $\pi$ due to reflection through the dielectric in mode 3.

Since the system is symmetric with input and output modes, the same thing happens with a superposition of output modes giving you a single input mode. It’s the destructive interference of amplitudes!

---

And for an all-optical implementation of a CNOT gate, you may look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403062).

Comment: *"if we were working with photons"* -- This really depends on the encoding!  For  polarization qubits, you rather want a wave plate!  --  Oh, and: How about linking to an accessible paper? :)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch made it clear that this was one of the ways to use photons. And sorry for the paywall! I have linked the arxiv version :)

Comment: Awesome!  (regarding the 2nd point).

Comment: Reading your edit, you did *not*: You made it clear that this is one way to do the Hadamard gate.  The point however is that there is more than one way to use photons as qubits. Your answer still gives the impression that "using photons as qubits" is well-defined, i.e., there is a unique way.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, I said, “*...if we were working with photons, one way to realise...*” I think it’s clear that this is only one of the ways to use photons.